# Postgres: PreparedStatement incorrectly identifying datatypes

Tags: postgresql, insert, prepared-statement, auto-increment

I am having trouble getting this command to execute correctly. The first column of the table is an auto-incrementing integer, so I wish to start entering data at column 2. When I do the following:

```
PREPARE fooplan (text, smallint, smallint, text, date, timestamp with time zone) as 
INSERT INTO "table" VALUES($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);
EXECUTE fooplan('Add New Record', 2, 2, 'User', '1999-Jan-08', '04:05:06');
```

I get this error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  column "category_id" is of type smallint but expression is of type text
LINE 2: insert into "MOP" values($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);
                                     ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
In statement:
prepare fooplan (text, smallint, smallint, text, date, time without time zone) as 
insert into "MOP" values($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);
execute fooplan('Add New Mop', 2, 2, 'User', '1999-Jan-08', '04:05:06');
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to insert values, but not specify the first field value then you need to state which columns you're inserting into.

I dont know what your columns are called so I've just called them column_1, column_2 etc.

```
prepare fooplan (text, smallint, smallint, text, date, timestamp with time zone)
INSERT INTO MOP(column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6, column_7) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, £4, $5, $6);
```

Answer (score 1):

The number after the `$` refers to parameter order.

```
INSERT INTO "table" VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
```

In addition to that you will have to name the columns you are inserting into:

```
INSERT INTO "table" (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) 
VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
```